# How "frequent" or how "frequently"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

What would be the correct grammar? Should I use adverb after `how`?

> How frequent you do this?

or

> How frequently you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the adverb **frequently** here, it needs agreement with the *verb* (do frequently):

> How frequently do you do this?

For comparison: the adjective **frequent** would agree with a *noun*:

> How *frequent* are your *trips* there?

Comment: It does not agree with the verb, it modifies the verb...